# "git log" "tag: " inconsistent across repos

Tags: git

I have a script that uses "git log --decorate --pretty=oneline" and seaches the results for the tags using "grep 'tag: '" and this works for most of our repos but it seems lately we have seen a couple of new repos return results to the script without the 'tag: '

Example:

```
(HEAD, tag: 1.0.0-DEV, origin/development, development)
```

VS

```
(HEAD, 1.0.0-DEV, origin/development, development)
```

If I run the script commands interactively as the same user I do not get the same result so I am at a loss as to why in a couple of repos the script gets a different result the the same user would interactively.

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what might cause that particular problem.  There were some fixes and changes in Git versions 2.4.x around decorations, and a more recent one in 2.13.1 to fix `log.decorate=no` (which simply was not obeyed), but none of these would explain why the word `tag:` goes missing, yet the tag itself comes out.

A more likely source for the problem would be some sort of i18n issue, but [the `tag:` prefix inserted by `log-tree.c` is not run through the translation system in the first place](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231/log-tree.c#L261) (note the lack of `_("tag: ")`).

The only way you *should* be able to see:

```
(HEAD, 1.0.0-DEV, origin/development, development)
```

is if there *is* a *branch* named `1.0.0-DEV` and *not* a *tag* named `1.0.0-DEV`.  (If both were present, you should see both `1.0.0-DEV` and `tag: 1.0.0-DEV`.)  But this should be consistent: every user, running `git log --decorate` over that particular commit, should see the same thing.

(You can of course use `git for-each-ref` to display every reference in full, to make sure that these repositories do have the correct set of references.)